# Elixir Supervise multiple RabbitMQ Consumer workers

Tags: rabbitmq, elixir, erlang-otp, erlang-supervisor

I have been following along the RabbitMQ Work Queues tutorial for Elixir ([Elixir Work Queues](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-elixir.html)) which works quite nicely. On top of that I am now trying to get multiple consumers started and monitored by a Supervisor.

This last portion is proving to be a bit tricky. If I run the below code in 2 separate iex sessions, both are getting & handling messages from RabbitMQ.

**Client (consumer)**

```
defmodule MT.Client do
  require Logger

  @host Application.get_env(:mt, :host)
  @username Application.get_env(:mt, :username)
  @password Application.get_env(:mt, :password)
  @channel Application.get_env(:mt, :channel)

  def start_link do
    MT.Client.connect
  end

  def connect do
    {:ok, connection} = AMQP.Connection.open(host: @host, username: @username, password: @password)
    {:ok, channel} = AMQP.Channel.open(connection)

    AMQP.Queue.declare(channel, @channel, durable: true)
    AMQP.Basic.qos(channel, prefetch_count: 1)

    AMQP.Basic.consume(channel, @channel)

    Logger.info "[*] Waiting for messages"

    MT.Client.loop(channel)
  end

  def loop(channel) do
    receive do
      {:basic_deliver, payload, meta} ->
        Logger.info "[x] Received #{payload}"
        payload
        |> to_char_list
        |> Enum.count(fn x -> x == ?. end)
        |> Kernel.*(1000)
        |> :timer.sleep
        Logger.info "[x] Done."
        AMQP.Basic.ack(channel, meta.delivery_tag)

        MT.Client.loop(channel)
    end
  end
end
```

**Supervisor**

```
defmodule MT.Client.Supervisor do
  use Supervisor
  require Logger

  @name MTClientSupervisor

  def start_link do
    Supervisor.start_link(__MODULE__, :ok, name: @name)
  end

  def init(:ok) do
    children = [
      worker(MT.Client, [], restart: :transient, id: "MTClient01"),
      worker(MT.Client, [], restart: :transient, id: "MTClient02"),
      worker(MT.Client, [], restart: :transient, id: "MTClient03")
    ]
    supervise(children, strategy: :one_for_one)
  end
end
```

**When running that in an iex session:**

```
iex -S mix
MT.Client.Supervisor.start_link
```

**Following is logged:**

```
08:46:50.746 [info] [*] Waiting for messages
08:46:50.746 [info] [x] Received {"job":"TestMessage","data":{"message":"message........"}}
08:46:58.747 [info] [x] Done.
08:46:58.748 [info] [x] Received {"job":"TestMessage","data":{"message":"last........"}}
08:47:06.749 [info] [x] Done.
```

So clearly there in only 1 consumer active, which is consuming the messages sequentially.

**Running the below in 2 iex sessions:**

```
MT.Client.start_link
```

I'm not adding the logs here, but in this case I get 2 consumes handling messages at the same time

I am sure that I am simply not grasping the required details for Agent/GenServer/Supervisor. Anyone can point out what needs to be changed to MT.Client & MT.Client.Supervisor above to achieve the idea of having multiple consumers active on the same channel?

Also; I'm been experimenting with spawning a Consumer agent and using the resulting pid in `AMQP.Basic.consume(channel, @channel, pid)` - but that's failing as well.

Comment: Could you try updating your code in `Supervisor`s `init` function where you are defining workers to add them unique names? You could add this as a parameter after `:id` which should be an atom. You can try using similar value of `: id`, eg. `id: "MTClient01", name: :"MTClient01"`.

Comment: I've tried these 2 variations (with name:, with and without double quotes) `worker(MT.Client, [], restart: :transient, id: "MTClient01", name: :MTClient01)` and `worker(MT.Client, [], restart: :transient, id: "MTClient01", name: :"MTClient01")` for the 3 workers. Each time with the same results as before: 1 consumer accepting the messages. The RabbitMQ monitor also only show 1 connection